# Difference between endl and '\n'

Tags: c++, stream, outputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

I have a simple program I tested and I realise that `endl` wreaks havoc on my program. Using endl, my program ran in **100+ ms** while working with `'\n'`, the time dropped to **~50ms**.
Can anyone tell why is there such a difference?

P.S. I did read other posts that somehow explained what each of them are doing, but does `std::flush` really take so much time?
Or could there be another possible explanation?

Comment: endl also flushes the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`endl` has extra expensive `flush()` operation

**27.7.3.8 Standard basic_ostream manipulators [ostream.manip]**

```
namespace std {
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
}
1 Effects: Calls os.put(os.widen(’\n’)), then os.flush().
2 Returns: os.
```

Answer (score 6):

`std::endl` writes a newline, **and flushes the buffer**. As you have discovered, the flush can be a rather expensive operation.

Comment: It's quite strange to me that this thing can double the execution time. Thank you

Comment: @BujancaMihai: If there's doubt in your mind, compare the timings of: (1) `endl`; (2) `\n`; (3) `\n` followed by `flush`.

Comment: No doubt, I already tried and the difference is obvious. I was aware that the `flushing` occurs but not that it is such an expensive operation. Many thanks

Comment: @BujancaMihai: maybe the cost of the flush depends on how much things you have to flush, so it's hard to predict how expensive the operation will be.